# Client Management System with user-friendly interface

Tags: database, data-visualization, data

Do you know of some self-hosted Client Management System to manage our clients data, so we can do things like searches, filters, reordering, grouping clients by criteria, etc?

The most important thing would be a cool, eye-catching user interface that makes it easy to work with.

The data is in excel xlsx.

Thanks,

Comment: By "self-hosted" you mean something web-based? Or shall it have native clients (in the latter case, for what OS(es))? And any price limit to it?

Comment: I was thinking something Open Source and yes, web based. Something that accepts our own excel columns or has borad import capabilities.

Comment: As for the Excel: Are you talking about "simple tables" (i.e. would exporting them as CSV be an option)? And then, would you want to "view only" – or shall editing be possible (in the latter case, in what format(s) would results need to be exported)? // Besides, it's hard to tell what would fit; "client data" is quite a bit broad. But maybe someone has an idea…